# Does IE8 have rendering bugs like 6 or 7?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, xhtml

Does IE8 have rendering bugs like IE6 or IE7? If I make my site render correctly in Firefox 3.5, will it look the same in IE8, or will additional changes / hacks / etc be needed?

I want to make my site IE8 compatible. Do I need to do something extra for that?

Update: 6 march 2010

Is there a possibility that I will have to add conditional CSS for IE8 or not?

Comment: why it's question of cross browser compatibility?

Comment: This absolutely belongs on stackoverflow, except for the fact that it's a very poorly composed question.

Comment: It is a very broad question, but I don't think superuser can really help him out.

Comment: @Robert: I don't understand why it should be on superuser. It's a programming question, not a user question.

Comment: And the "let's dump our trash on SuperUser" tic strikes again

Comment: @ChssPly76 thx for improving grammar

Comment: @ChssPly76 please change grammar again i accidently presses rollback button

Comment: Well, you can accidentally roll it back again :-)

Comment: This totally belongs on SO, why would anyone think it belongs on SU??

Comment: Check out the revision history. The initial question was pretty bad and I could understand how it could have been understood incorrectly at that time.

Comment: Well the question might arguably have been bad but how does that translate to "dump it on SU"?

Comment: Doesn't this question belong on doctype?

Comment: @Ether - Why? it's related to browser rendering.

Comment: @Ether: It could, but web-development questions seem to be pretty popular around these parts too. @jitendra: doctype is specifically for web-design, unlike Stack Overflow which was intended to be specifically for programming.

Comment: It may not have bugs like 6 or 7. It could have them like 1 or 2 or three... I don't know how many.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**All browsers have their various quirks and** no browser is guaranteed to display or act the same as another. While W3C is making great strides to expand the functionality that should be standardized, **many RFCs are not yet to the [Recommendation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3C_recommendation) stage**, which is the stage that means it will no longer change and are more likely to be acceptable standards to develop on. **Because of this, it is imperative that you ensure your site works** in, at minimum, the browsers **within your focus group**.

First, use [reset.css](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/). Both try to serve the same goal (consistency fixes between browsers), but each attacks the problem from different angles. So make sure you choose the one that works best for you. While not perfect, they get pretty darn close in all browsers, which is more than you can say without it.

Second, check out [QuirksMode](https://quirksmode.org/) to see the [various browser compatability](https://quirksmode.org/compatibility.html) with standards (whether those standards are in recommended stage or not). This is where you can decide on the features you will use that match the compatibility with your focus group.

Third, with your new power of a 'consistent' css base, and knowledge of what browsers support what, be sure to read, embrace, preach, and apply progressive enhancement techniques (see articles I like on it below). The power of progressive enhancement is to use what does work instead of trying to shoehorn a fat foot into a slim shoe.

*Articles on progressive enhancement:*

1. http://www.alistapart.com/articles/understandingprogressiveenhancement
2. http://www.alistapart.com/articles/progressiveenhancementwithcss
3. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement

Lastly, install any other browsers that you consider in your focus group. Doing so will allow you to test, without question, the appearance on the page.

On windows, I recommend installing IE9 to be able to switch rendering modes to older versions of IE. While these rendering modes are not perfect, in most cases they can be just as reliable as the real thing. If you cannot install IE9, I feel sorry for you, but, luckily, IE8 gives you similar power for rendering modes.

On anything else (or even windows if you want the real IE browsers rather than emulation), you need to get a windows virtual instance running. There are many ways to get then and MS even provides various images of instances specifically for developers to be able to test old versions of IE. See [this blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/ie7-virtual-pc-image-and-ie6-virtual-pc-image-refresh) for more details on where to get the MS supplied IE6 and IE7 VPCs.

Using these tools you should be more than able to develop a design that will look -- no -- work and degrade gracefully in 100% of browsers and validate that it is implemented correctly. While it can be a bit daunting, this will greatly reduce the chance of display/js related bug upon release.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, IE 8 still has some rendering bugs. Most of them are fixed, but I think that these for example are still there:

- The text-align attribute is applied to block elements, not just inline elements.
- Content of elements is still one character high even if there is no content.

Of course it also depends on what doctype you are using. Without a proper doctype the page renders in quirks mode, which pretty much throws the browser back to IE 4.

If you are using different style sheets for different browser/version combinations, you will need another one. IE 8 doesn't behave exactly as any other browser or IE version. I always use a single style sheet for all browsers, and I didn't have to make any changes at all to it to make it work for IE 8.

Comment: Why the downvote? It's pretty pointless if you don't say what it is that you don't like.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on @Kevin's and @James' answers, another good resource is [Browser Shots](http://browsershots.org/) to get screen captures of your site on different browsers and platforms. Very useful for testing browsers/versions that you don't have access to, especially for tricky CSS layouts.

I've used it to view output for Mac and Linux browsers since I work in a Windows-only shop.

Note that the URL must be externally accessible; if you're developing on your local box you'll need to poke a hole through your firewall and maybe setup a dynamic DNS name instead of an IP address.

Comment: Yeah, that service can be nice, so +1. Sometimes it is just too hard to pull off a publicly accessible site. I find it easier to install the major browsers and IE Tester (gives IE5.5 - IE8 access on XP or above) on windows instead. everything else is ususally too obscure to care about unless a bug report comes in.

Comment: Adobe also has a project at browserlab.adobe.com  It requires a login, but results are nearly instant and the interface is nice with the tabs.

Answer (score 2):

**Edited** I moved one paragraph and rewrote it based on some feedback.

If you explore http://quirksmode.org you will find compatibility pages that explain the differences between various browsers, including Firefox 3.5 and IE8.

Most likely you will be making changes, but that will depend on what you are using, as there are many similarities, that won't require changes.

Comment: Whether he'll be making **any** changes really depends on his site. IE8 has gotten better comparing to previous versions; while it's still  not ideal (and by far), many core things are supported reasonably well.

Comment: @ChssPly76 - If you design your site for FF3.5 then you won't be taking into account all the CSS issues, for example, of IE8. It is better, but no where near perfect, and FF3.5 is supporting newer standards better than IE8.

Comment: *insert browser e-peen fight here*

Comment: You're missing my point. For all you know OP's website may consist of 3 text paragraphs on white background or be entirely Flash-based. There's no arguing that there are things supported by FF (Safari / Opera / Chrome / ...) that are not (correctly) supported by IE8. But you don't know whether OP will make use of any of them; therefore you can't say "you will be making many changes".

Comment: @ChssPly76 - That is why I suggested the compatibility pages on quirksmode. It will help him understand what the differences are and see if they will actually impact them, but, I expect he will need to make changes.  It will require some research on the part of the OP.

Comment: if my site looking good in IE7 then can i make exact look for IE8 just by adding this line in head <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />